# Paperclip in Rails 4 - Strong Parameters Forbidden Attributes Error

Tags: paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, paperclip-validation

Having a problem with a Paperclip upload in Rails 4 - failing on ForbiddenAttributesError (strong parameters validation).  Have the latest paperclip gem and latest rails 4 gems.

I have a model "Image" with an attached file "upload" in the model:

```
has_attached_file :upload, :styles => { :review => ["1000x1200>", :png], :thumb => ["100x100>", :png]}, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

The image model was created with a scaffold, and I added paperclip migrations.  The form partial was updated to use

```
f.file_field :upload
```

the form generates what appears to be a typical set of paperclip params, with the image param containing the upload.  I am also passing a transaction_id in the image model, so it should be permitted.  But that's it - the image and the transaction ID.

I expected to be able to write the following in my controller to whitelist my post - but it failed:

```
def image_params
  params.require(:image).permit(:transaction_id, :upload)
end
```

So I got more explicit - but that failed too:

```
def image_params
  params.require(:image).permit(:transaction_id, :upload => [:tempfile, :original_filename, :content_type, :headers])
end
```

I'm a bit frustrated that Rails 4 is not showing me what ForbiddenAttributesError is failing on in a development environment - it is supposed to be showing the error but it does not - would be a nice patch to ease development.  Or perhaps everyone else is getting something that I am missing!  Thanks much for the help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I understand what happened here now - and will leave this up in the hope it helps someone else.  I was porting code from a rails 3 project and missed the line that created the image:

```
@image = current_user.images.new(params[:image])
```

In rails 4 this is incorrect (I beleive).  I updated to

```
@image = current_user.images.new(image_params)
```

and that solved my problem.

Comment: What did you end up putting in your params.permit() to get this to work?

Comment: in my case I had a model "Image" with a paperclip attachment 'image_file'.  The paperclip migration creates several columns in the db, such as image_file_file_name etc, but all you have to do is params.require(:image).permit(:image_file) to allow paperclip to work its magic.

Comment: Thanks so much! That is not intuitive, but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your first one should have worked. This is what I use for my projects.

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
  end

  def create
    @user.galleries.new(gallery_params)
  end

  private

  #note cover_image is the name of paperclips attachment filetype(s)
  def gallery_params
    params.require(:gallery).permit(:cover_image)
  end
end
```